# Are we ever going to be introduced to Ryou's downstairs neighbor?

Tags: koufuku-graffiti

As of episode 8 of Koufuku Graffiti, there's been at least one shot per episode in which Ryou's downstairs neighbor is briefly shown (usually standing on her balcony folding clothes or something).

[image: the downstairs neighbor]

Is she ever going to be introduced as a character, or is she more just a running joke?

Comment: could happen in the last episode but even if it doesn't happen then it can still happen in a later season. Maya Matsumoto in Wokring!! only had a speaking role at the end of both seasons and only properly introduced at the end of season 2. could be the same here

Comment: Not until Ryou enters high school~ Her name's Yuki [Uchiki](http://myanimelist.net/character/118397/Yuki_Uchiki).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by [krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/%ca%9e%c9%b9%c9%90z%c7%9d%c9%b9) in the comment, she is Yuki Uchiki. She is finally introduced in episode 10 *Chewy, Melty.* (Japanese title: *Hamohamo, Michichi.*) when Kirin eavesdropped on her phone conversation and accidentally fell (and safely landed) on her veranda.

In the anime, episode 10 happened around January (as the next episode happened in February, and the previous episode happened on New Year's Eve). At this time, Yuki was a graduating undergraduate student, while Ryou and Kirin were preparing for their high school entrance exam in March. According to [her wiki page](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%86%85%E6%9C%A8%E3%83%A6%E3%82%AD) on nicovideo, she is going to work as a librarian at the same high school where Ryou and Kirin goes to.

Comment: I don't know whether the manga is the same, since I haven't read it.

Comment: You should, it's delicious.